# Facebook Graph API only returning 15 photos with no pagination options

Tags: facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to download all of the photos that I've been tagged in from facebook.

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=blah`

Returns a `data[]` with 15 pictures and a paging object:

`'paging':
{
    'cursors': 
    {
        'after':  'afterHash', 
        'before': 'beforeHash'
    }
}`

I expected to see `next` and `previous` urls in `paging` to get at more photos.

Calling: `https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=blah&type=tagged&after=afterHash` returns an empty `data[]`

Adding `&limit=14` to the request returns 14 pictures and the `next` url that I would expect. Getting that `next` url only returns 1 picture though, for a total of 15 again.

Further details on the pictures being returned by the api call:

Created Times range from 2013-08-25 to 2015-10-10
5 photos uploaded by friends and tagged, 10 uploaded by myself.

When I look at "/Photos/Photos of You" from my profile page I see many more pictures than are being returned by the API (50+ for 2015, hundreds in years before that). The 15 that are being returned are a mixture of pictures that I have uploaded and those uploaded by friends who then tagged me.

Comment: and you are sure you´re not tagged in only 15 photos?

Comment: When I look at "/Photos/Photos of You" from my profile page I see many more pictures than are being returned by the API. The 15 that are being returned are a mixture of pictures that I have uploaded and those uploaded by friends who then tagged me.

Answer (score 2):

By default reading from the photos edge includes all photos a person has been tagged in.

> Required Permission : user_photos

Referance: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos

You can make following API Call. Because no one tagged in 999,999,999,999,999 Photos.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?fields=images{source}&limit=999999999999999&access_token=xxxxx
```

You can retrieve all photos which was allowed on Timeline. You can see those from here:
https://www.facebook.com/your_username_or_id/photos_of

Here is the sample php code which will get source for all photos using curl:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl,array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER =>1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?fields=images{source}&limit=999999999999999&access_token=xxxxx',
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
));
$array = json_decode(curl_exec($curl),true);
curl_close($curl);

for( $i = 0; $i<count($array['data']);$i++) 
{
    echo  $array['data'][$i]['images'][0]['source']."</br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/your_username_or_id/photos_of shows hundreds of photos, but making the api call you suggested still only returns 15 photos. Any ideas?

Comment: Graph Api Returns Only Public Photos. That mean photo's privacy must set to PUBLIC. Privacy can be controlled by the person who tagged you.

Comment: Or Your friend must allow that app to his account. If the photo's privacy set to other than public.

Answer (score 0):

First of all was your access token requested with the `user_photos` permission?

Also, as taken from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo:

> A user access token may read a photo that user is tagged in if they
>   have granted the user_photos or user_posts permission. However, in
>   some cases the photo's owner's privacy settings may not allow your
>   application to access it.

Most likely though, you need to ask for all albums (via `https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=blah`) and then in turn ask each of these for all the photos. The 15 photos you are retrieving are *the photos from the first ever album created* as mentioned in [Get all photos of a page using Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037926/get-all-photos-of-a-page-using-facebook-api)

Try it out here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Falbums&version=v2.5

Comment: The quote that you posted, does that suggest that a photo owner can have privacy settings that would prevent me from downloading a picture via the api, even if I was tagged in it and it showed up in "/Photos/Photos of You" on my profile page?

Asking for albums just shows me albums that I have created, not pictures that other people have tagged me in.